# What is an example of ideals such that $IJ\neq JI$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples

> Let $R$ be an rng.
>
> Let $I,J$ be ideals of $R$.
>
> What is an example of $IJ\neq JI$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the free algebra $k\langle x,y\rangle $. The ideals $I=(x)$ and $J=(y)$ are such that $IJ\neq  JI$.